# Stuttering Color Transitions

Tags: color

I'm having an issue with stuttering color transitions. It seems like some steps are being skipped.

I've tried adjusting various settings like bezier and linear transitions, keyframe intervals, motion blurs, playing in different software, ...

Might this be something with the color space (sRGB) or color depth?

Kind regards

[image]

Comment: you don't give enough details, please show some screenshots of your object, node editor, etc...

Comment: Welcome to BSE @extur2 please upload the file and add the link to your question, otherwise, no one will be able to help you without enough information